# What does "LOCKED_TRACK constraint reserved for Locked Track" mean?

Tags: objects, constraints

I am working on the rig of a jet-fighter with no bones, using empties to emulate a hinge for the different parts that flap up etc; for this I use two empties: one to act as a hinge, the other as target. I applied a [*locked track*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Tracking/Locked_Track) constraint to the hinge, but when I select the hinge empty and I apply the Locked track constraint I get the following cryptic error in the properties window where the actual constraint was suppose to be:

> LOCKED_TRACK constraint reserved for Locked Track.

I have researched the internet and I could not find any information on the error, just the wiki manual page that confirms that LOCKED TRACK is exactly what I need.

The little info I found did not address my problem at all, but ways of using the LOCKED TRACK constraint. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I never used a *Locked track constraint* but using shape keys could be an alternative for animations without bones.

If you separate <kbd>P</kbd> the flaps and parent them to the plane <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> you could add two shape keys and animate them by keyframing the value:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution; just upgrade to Blender 2.70.5 that resolved the problem straight away.